# translating list items using i18n angular

Tags: angular, internationalization

i've been looking for a way to translate a hole list item using a single id but i was getting an error (ERROR in xliff parse errors:
Unexpected tag (") for every item is there any solution

i've tried this:

app.component.html

`<ul i18n="@@list">
     <li> hello </li>
     <li> welcome </li>
    </ul>`

translate.fr.xlf

```
 `<trans-unit id="list" datatype="html">
    <source>
        <li> hello </li>
        <li> welcome </li>
    </source>
    <target>
        <li> bonjour </li>
        <li> bienvenue </li>
    </target>
    <context-group purpose="location">
      <context context- type="sourcefile">
           src/app/app.component.html
      </context>
      <context context-type="linenumber">29</context>
    </context-group>
  </trans-unit>`
```

the expected result is that the list will be translated from english to french but i keep getting this error for every item of the list:
ERROR in xliff parse errors: Unexpected tag ("
please is there any solution for this, i can still translate the whole list by adding an id for every item and translate it separately but it would save me so much time translating them at once, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow [the guide](https://angular.io/guide/i18n). Useing `ng xi18n`, as the guide explains, to generate your messages file, will not generate what you posted in your question. I just did it, and here's what it generated:

```
      <trans-unit id="list" datatype="html">
        <source>
  <x id="START_LIST_ITEM" ctype="x-li" equiv-text="&lt;li&gt;"/> hello <x id="CLOSE_LIST_ITEM" ctype="x-li" equiv-text="&lt;/li&gt;"/>
  <x id="START_LIST_ITEM" ctype="x-li" equiv-text="&lt;li&gt;"/> welcome <x id="CLOSE_LIST_ITEM" ctype="x-li" equiv-text="&lt;/li&gt;"/> 
</source>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/app.component.html</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">9</context>
        </context-group>
      </trans-unit>
```

Respect that file structure, and I guess everything will work as expected.